# What is actor token in Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens?

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, asp.net-core, jwt

[documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/dn464112(v%3Dvs.114)), also class `TokenValidationParameters` contains property

`TokenValidationParameters ActorValidationParameters { get; set; }`

with summary  "Gets or sets a value indicating if an actor token is detected, whether it should be validated".

Is it related with this [definition](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Actor)?

Answer (score 3):

The actor claim (`act`) is part of the [OAuth 2.0 Token Exchange](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-token-exchange-16.html) specification. Token Exchange basically describes a general mechanism to obtain security tokens and especially covers impersonation and delegation. For this purpose, the actor claim is useful to identity the involved parties in a delegated scenario.

The current draft of the spec [explains the claim like this](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-ietf-oauth-token-exchange-16.html#rfc.section.4.1):

> The `"act"` (actor) claim provides a means within a JWT to express that delegation has occurred and identify the acting party to whom authority has been delegated. The `"act"` claim value is a JSON object and members in the JSON object are claims that identify the actor. The claims that make up the `"act"` claim identify and possibly provide additional information about the actor. For example, the combination of the two claims `"iss"` and `"sub"` might be necessary to uniquely identify an actor.

For common OAuth purposes, you can ignore the claim and do not need to validate it.